# Selenium find button with multiple classes

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Does anyone know how to get an element that has multiple classes ? Hhe html object unfortunately does not have an ID...so I'm trying to work with the CSS_Selector...I've also looked at other StackOverflow questions but they didn't really help me.

note : I know for 100% the way the classes is being used at that button is not being used again in this page.

what I've tried so far :

```py
wa = WebDriverWait(driver, 25)
fullScreen = wa.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.vjs-fullscreen-control.vjs-control.vjs-button')))
fullScreen.click()
```

```html
<button class="vjs-fullscreen-control vjs-control vjs-button" type="button" title="Fullscreen" aria-disabled="false"><span aria-hidden="true" class="vjs-icon-placeholder"></span><span class="vjs-control-text" aria-live="polite">Fullscreen</span></button>
```

Could I have done something wrong with the selector string ?
Because I'm getting an timeout exception, that would mean it could not find the element.

Comment: try finding the element by its xpath

Comment: I've also tried that but it's not working... any ideas ?

Comment: Did you tried the css in the browser devtools and see if it's working there. I believe the element that you are trying to access might be in a frame.